# Arrow function not show with React class prototype

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to log all the function class in React class component, search the web and ask everywhere and i got this

```js
const listOfFunctionClass = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(MyClass.prototype)
```

It work! But problem is it only show the lifeCycle and function when i try to log `console.log(listOfFunctionClass)`, **do not include arrow function**

**Example**

```js
class Foo extends React.Component{
  functionA(){} ==>will log
  functionB = () =>{}  ===> will not show on log
  componentDidUpdate() ==> will log on log
}
```

It will have an array like `[functionA, componentDidUpdate]`

**So how can i add arrow function on proptype?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can technically add an arrow function onto the prototype by assigning to the `.prototype` property outside:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
}
Foo.prototype.fn = () => {
  // ...
}
```

Due to how arrow functions work, you won't be able to access the `this` of the instance inside it. Such an arrow function would only be useable if all the data it needed was passed to it.

But using a standard method would make more sense in most situations

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  fn() {
    // ...
```

or a class field

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  fn = () => {
```

You can't easily detect what class fields are on a class, because they're syntax sugar for

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.fn = () => {
```

They're not on the prototype - they're only on instances. You'll have to examine the instance itself to see what properties it has in order to find such a class field.

```js
const builtinReactInstanceProperties = ['props', 'context', 'refs', 'updater'];
class Foo extends React.Component {
  fn = () => {}
}
const instance = new Foo();
console.log(
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(instance)
    .filter(propName => !builtinReactInstanceProperties.includes(propName))
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

That said, this sort of dynamic analysis of what properties exist on an object is pretty weird. I can't think of when such an approach would be the best one.